# php include cause internal server error 500

Tags: javascript, php

In my PHP website when i m adding include('1.php'); line inside a function causing "Internal Server Error 500"

```
function load()
{
    include("lib/data/1.php");
}
```

this function is called via URL

```
http://localhost/xm/index.php?p=events&q=load
```

'q' parameter is for load function

but when i directly call 1.php file like :

```
http://localhost/xm/lib/data/1.php
```

it works fine

1.php generates XML File like String.

now in js i want to call load function

```
scheduler.load('index.php?p=events&q=load');
```

this function takes url which returns XML file like string. i want load function to include 1.php file and return XML like string.

Comment: check your error log for more details !!

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty nothing in error.log file

Comment: Double check your paths. If you are calling this from a dir different than `xm`, you will have errors

Comment: @NorthBridge paths r correct.... :\

Comment: Paste the contents of 1.php and index.php in the question so we can see what's going wrong

Comment: @NorthBridge total 8 files r called and included in 1.php all files are nested which extract data from mysql and convert to XML Formal

Answer (score 0):

For including a php page into another page.
you should use this `<?php include "1.php";?>` give the exact path of 1.php in the include command.
If u need any values to be send from one page to another use query string and catch the values  using GET method and do the navigation.